# Can we comment out RMarkdown so that it's not included in the exported HTML?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to comment out a section of code in my RMarkdown. I know that I can use the `<!-- -->` syntax to add comments, but these comments still appear in the rendered HTML (although hidden). Is there a way to create real comments that are ignored during rendering and don't appear in the exported document source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap everything in  `~~~{=comment}` ... `~~~` to get it ignored:

```
Normal text

~~~{=comment}
this will be ignored

This, too!
~~~

No longer in a comment.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could specify with `echo` to code lines to show in your output like this:

````
---
date: "2022-12-13"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=2:4}
# This comment should not be shown
rnorm(3)
# But keep this comment in output html
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't show the first comment.